# devise sign In user automatically based on authentication_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to send an email with a user with a link that automatically sign him in based on authentication_token or something similar? (No login required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. Just send a link to login with a query string containing the username that should be logged in. When your login code gets this, sign the user in.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to generate a unique token instead of just using email/username
And also you should tell users that the link can be used to sign in since they might forward it to others.